# Right Align end of line String.format inside dialog.message

Tags: java, android, dialog, alignment, string.format

At the end of line of dialog title I want to have part of my String. I know how to move to right for some chars but I want it at the end of Title line. For now I do it like that :

```
dialog.setTitle("Progress " + String.format("%40s","1/10"));
```

But for biggest screens it is placed on the middle of screen. How to do that to have it all the time at the end of this line ?

[image: this is how it looks hardcoded by chars]

Comment: can you please add some screen shots to get more idea about it

Comment: ok I add image, so at one screen (small one) when I use "%40s" is enough but for biggest screens it's not enough and I want it for all screens to be on right side